# Form submit cancelled and looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, setinterval

I am having a problem where I am submitting a file as part of a standard HTML form, and the file uploads, however - this process seems to be stuck in a never ending loop... so the file uploads over and over.

The form is submitted via jQuery, i.e. `$('myform').submit();` and isn't an ajax request. Looking in the chrome network console, the request is "cancelled" and 0 bytes are transmitted.

What is causing this loop?

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour of searching around, I upgraded chrome and the console showed a warning about an JavaScript Interval `timer = setInterval(count_seconds, 1000)`.

This function was simply counting the number of elapsed seconds. I've never come across this before, but it seems that Chrome prevents the submission of the form while there is an interval actively running?!

I have now cleared the interval using `clearInterval(count_seconds)` and `timer=null;` for good measure, before submitting the form, and that has fixed the issue.

Answering my own question to save others the headache, but if anyone can explain this odd (new?) behaviour then that'd be great.